# Java-To check whether a string is even (FFHHIIJJ,UUURROOOR,..) or odd(IIREELO,PPGIUUUUS,..)

Tags: java, string, java-8

in java, I need to check whether the given string is even or odd.

Even  string will have equal number of characters ( HHEEPPDIDI,LLLQQMQMM,...)
Odd string will have unequal number of character (HRTRDFF, HIYUDHDA,...)

I tried with counting occurrence of each character and put that value into one INT Variable and compare the values of INT variable. But it doesn't look like a efficient code.

```
  int frequency = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(ch == str.charAt(i)) {
                ++frequency;
            }
```

Like this we can count each character and compare their value..But I want to know is there any other easy method or can we use any inbuilt methods to achieve it. We can use upto Java 8 version.
Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that your approach (if I understand it correctly) is the most efficient and simplest one: count each character. Compare the counts. If two counts are different, the string is odd, otherwise it’s even. If you need to, you may search for how to count the occurrences of each char in a string, it has been asked and answered several times before.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since stack Overflow is not a code writing or even an algorithm design service, I am voting to close this question as too broad. It’s not evil will, it’s more that broad questions tend not to work well here: they often either get no answers or no good answers or  no answers that will also be useful for other readers.

Comment: You’ve provided excellent examples, BTW. At first I didn’t understand how you defined even and odd strings, but your examples answered all my questions and cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in java 8 or higher versions, Is there any string API methods which
>   will simplify the requirement.

If you want to, in Java 8 and higher you may use the stream API, first for constructing the map of counts (in Java 9 starting from `str.chars()`), second for determining whether the map contains different counts. Whether you would consider it simpler is probably more a matter of taste (I’d probably consider it more advanced, and like it).

You can search the web and Stack Overflow for the details. If you get stuck, please post a new question, we’re here to help.

**EDIT:** I thought that by now you have had time to write your own code, so I am posting mine for you to compare if you want, without taking the fun and the learning away from you.

```
public static boolean isEven(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    Map<Integer, Long> counts = s.chars()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> ch, Collectors.counting()));
    Long someCount = counts.values().iterator().next();
    return counts.values()
            .stream()
            .allMatch(someCount::equals);
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    for (String s : new String[] {
            // Even strings
            "FFHHIIJJ", "UUURROOOR", "HHEEPPDIDI", "LLLQQMQMM", "abaccb", "abc", "d", "",
            // Odd strings
            "IIREELO", "PPGIUUUUS", "HRTRDFF", "HIYUDHDA", "abbc", "aabcc" }) {
        System.out.format("%-11s %b%n", s, isEven(s));
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> FFHHIIJJ    true
> UUURROOOR   true
> HHEEPPDIDI  true
> LLLQQMQMM   true
> abaccb      true
> abc         true
> d           true
>             true
> IIREELO     false
> PPGIUUUUS   false
> HRTRDFF     false
> HIYUDHDA    false
> abbc        false
> aabcc       false
> ```

Comment: Sure.Thank You so much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the input-string and add `char` by `char` into a data-structure(`HashMap`) with increased counter.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class A02 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(new A02().new Solution().check("HHEEPPDIDI"));
    System.out.println(new A02().new Solution().check("HHEEPPDID"));
    System.out.println(new A02().new Solution().check("HRTRDFF"));
}

class Solution
{
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

    public String check(String s)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if(hm.get(s.charAt(i))==null)
            {
                hm.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
            }
            else
            {
                hm.put(s.charAt(i),hm.get(s.charAt(i))+1);
            }
        }
        int first = 0;
        for(Character c : hm.keySet())
        {
            if(first==0) first=hm.get(c);
            if(first !=hm.get(c)) return "odd:"+s;
        }
        return "even:"+s;
    }
}
}
```

output:

`even:HHEEPPDIDI`
`odd:HHEEPPDID`
`odd:HRTRDFF`

It's not necessary the best algorithm regarding time but still it could be useful.
(there could be further optimization based on idea that if found 2 chars with different counters then it's odd)

Update for Java 8

```
public String check(String s)
{   
    //place the string into a map by chars with counter 
    Map<Integer,Long> map = 
    s.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t, Collectors.counting()));

    //check map by value - if values are the same then even and map size=1
    int size = 
    map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t)).keySet().size();

    if(size==1 || size==0) return "even:"+s;
    return "odd:"+s;
}
```

output for empty input:
`even:`

Comment: It’s a fine algorithm and code. My reservation is that if this is perhaps for a school assignment, you are helping too much, that is, the student needs not solve the assignment himself, but he would learn more from doing that.

Comment: Thx. @OleV.V. Yes, you maybe right. It might be for school, but at least if will understand what was done then is a progress. Sometime even complete example are good.(and he was trying something ...)

Comment: If the string contains many different characters, it will be more efficient to iterate through the value set of the map in the end rather than the key set (for a school assignment we shouldn’t mind, only note that for production code this would probably be a consideration).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, true also

Comment: Thank You so much Sir. Yeah..I tried to do it with LinkedhashMap..So in java 8 or higher versions, Is there any string API methods which will simplify the requirement.

Comment: Yes.My method which I tried is not good if the length of the string is more.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. The main idea is that you should iterate once through the string and after to count occurrence. With java 8 there is `Stream` class for iteration with various methods and `Collectors` for grouping.(counters). Could go and check that if want another solution. Simple solution are always good to try first and after you could enhance them as needed. Good Luck !

Comment: Updated the solution to work also with java-8 (3 lines of code). Hope to be useful for you.@OleV.V. use your suggestion with checking map by values.